# Azure Servicebus queue, BrokeredMessage.SequenceNumbers are not continuous

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, brokeredmessage

I'm using this **MessageReceiver.ReceiveBatchAsync Method** to receive a batch of messages from a service bus queue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.receivebatchasync?view=azure-dotnet

BrokeredMessage has a **SequenceNumber**, but sometimes the numbers are not continuous. Does that mean some messages lost.

How can I make this continuous?

Comment: Did you enable session and also what is the time to live for messages?

Comment: Session not enabled. The time to live for messages is 14 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BrokeredMessage has a SequenceNumber, but sometimes the numbers are not continuous. Does that mean some messages lost

The message sequence is set on the broker whenever the broker receives messages. So if you have scheduled messages and it's not the time yet, you'll have a gap between message sequence numbers. Messages are not lost once received by the broker. You shouldn't use sequence numbers as indicators.